# trouble deleting from mysql

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to using mysql.  I have an application that performs some basic querying.  I am also trying to run a simple delete statement -

```
delete from mydb.mytable
```

This table is a simple 2 column table with not keys or triggers or anything defined.  For some reason, the delete is not being performed.  If I run the statement from MySql Workbench in the query window, it works fine.  From the code, it does nothing.  I am not seeing any error messages.  I created a user with select, insert, update and delete rights to the schema.  I am able to do the insert fine, but the delete does not seem to be working.

Is there a setting for mysql that I am missing that will not allow me to perform the delete?
Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Probably a commit related issue ?

Comment: Are 100% sure your code is hitting the *same* database that you're hitting in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Yes, I am certain it is hitting the same database.  It may be a coding issue, before I start really picking apart the code, I wanted to be sure there wasn't a setting that I am missing somewhere.

Comment: What API/language is you application using ?

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, check if

- you are connected to the right database ;
- you are using transaction and forgetting 'commit' ;
- the user you use have enough permissions to delete from the table  .

As a side notice, if you want to delete all records, you should use `truncate` instead of `delete`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transactions? My first guess is that your code might be issuing a BEGIN TRANSACTION without a COMMIT.

Answer (score 0):

We would have to see some of your code to answer the question.

My guess is that you are not calling commit from your code. You can configure MySQL to auto-commit your queries, but this is usually not what you want.

Comment: yeah - that could be it.  I am able to perform the insert, but not the delete.  that's why I thought it may be a setting that I missed.  I have to look back through my code.  Thanks